# TypeError: this.Vue.axios is undefined when using axios HTTP driver

Tags: vue.js, vue-auth

Using `vue-auth` ([vue-auth on GitHub](https://github.com/websanova/vue-auth)) with the Axios HTTP driver I get the following error in the browser console:

`TypeError: this.Vue.axios is undefined`

**main.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import axios from "axios";
import "./libs/vue-auth";
```

**./libs/vue-auth.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import vueAuth from "@websanova/vue-auth";
import bearer from "@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/auth/bearer";
import axiosHttp from "@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/http/axios.1.x";
import vueRouter from "@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/router/vue-router.2.x";

// Vue.axios = axios;

Vue.use(vueAuth, {
  auth: bearer,
  http: axiosHttp,
  router: vueRouter
  // ...
});
```

When removing the comment for `Vue.axios = axios;` it seems to work at first glance. So I thought moving `Vue.axios = axios;` to the `main.js` but then again it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vue.axios` can be assigned either manually or with `vue-axios` plugin. Since `@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/http/axios.1.x` expects it to exist on plugin initialization:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
...

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
Vue.use(vueAuth, ...)
```

Moving `Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)` to main.js won't work because it should be evaluated before `./libs/vue-auth` is imported, and it cannot precede import according to JS specs. `Vue.use(...)` should either moved to main.js together, or they both should be located in `./lib` modules.